# Using all: unset; doesn't overwrite external styles

Tags: html, css

I'm loading two stylesheets on a page in this order:

```
plugin.css
styles.css
```

Both stylesheets are loading from my server.

Via `plugin.css`, there's the following class:

```
.plugin h1 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Via `styles.css`, I already have `<h1>` styles, like so:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-size: 2.625rem;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0.3333333333333333em;
}
```

To overwrite `plugin.css`, I'd usually do this within `styles.css`:

```
.plugin h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-size: 2.625rem;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0.3333333333333333em;
}
```

This isn't at all efficient as I'm repeating code I already have. I was hoping to use the following in `styles.css`:

```
.plugin h1 {
  all: unset;
}
```

**Or**

```
.plugin h1 {
  all: initial;
}
```

I was expecting `all: unset;` or `all: initial;` to clear the properties from `.plugin h1` and revert back to my default `<h1>` styles in `styles.css`, but it doesn't work.

Have I misunderstood how this works or am I missing something?

Comment: also just in case you are using IE. unset is unsupported
https://caniuse.com/#search=unset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `all: initial;` or  `all: unset;` it will remove all style and even make your `h1` tag an `inline element`. So resetting such way will actually increase your headache! If you really want to `unset` the previous property then try `unset` or `initial` for an individual property like this.

```
.plugin h1 {
      font-size: unset;
      line-height: unset;
      margin-bottom: unset;
     }

.plugin h1 {
     font-size: 42px;
     font-size: 2.625rem;
     line-height: 1;
     margin-bottom: 0.3333333333333333em;
    }
```

After `unset` the code, you can come with your intended style like this. *But I'm not sure why you getting `font-size:` two times! You know **the last one will only work!***

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was hoping `unset` would be the answer of my dreams and unhook the class properties.